# Cloudstack VM on NAS

Tags: cloud, virtual-machine, virtualization, apache-cloudstack, network-storage

I have a synology (DS412+) NAS installed on my network. 
Is it possible to configure my CloudStack to store my VM on NAS instead of local machine.

can anyone help me

Answer (score 1):

CloudStack's storage model for VMs allows users to place the virtual hard disk (VHD) on primary storage or local storage.  Local storage corresponds to the file system of the hypervisor's Dom0 (XenServer terminology).  Primary storage corresponds to shared storage, e.g. NFS.

Look to see if your NAS can be accessed via NFS, or another file sharing protocol for which CloudStack has support.  If not, then mount your NAS on the hypervisor's Dom0 of you hypervisor manually, and tell CloudStack to use local storage for VMs.

Further support is available from user mailing list for Apache CloudStack.  [Sign up here](http://cloudstack.apache.org/mailing-lists.html)

Answer (score 1):

I personally use a Synology DS410 as both the primary and secondary storage for CloudStack in my lab. Since Synology supports both NFS and iSCSI, you have the following options:

1. Use Synology NFS or iSCSI for the primary storage
2. Use Synology NFS share for the secondary storage

Answer (score 0):

Ashok,

Maybe you have found the solution already but anyway...

1. In the Synology box, Via the Control Panel, Create a Shared Folder SHAREDNFS [or whatever you want to call it.
2. Then, select the folder and click on Privileges option and chose NFS Privileges.
   New window opens and you will be required to type in the IP of the machine which will have permissions to access this folder - type your Hosts IP[s]. If you have say 3 xenservers, then IP of each one should be entered.
   192.168.1.10
   192.168.1.11
   192.168.1.n
3. On the status bar of that same window you will see the path to this folder i.e. /volume1/SHAREDNFS. Remember this as you will need it when you want to connect to it.

Now, from this point I will give instructions as if you're doing it on XenCenter, but this should not be very different in CloudStack.

In the XenCenter click on the New Storage Pool
Select NFS VHD
Change the name if you wish
now you need to type the IP address of the Synology box say it's 192.168.1.100 and add the path that I said earlier you need to remember: 192.168.1.100:/volume1/SHAREDNFS
Click on Scan 
And this should be it!

Hope this helps.